# JavaScript onclick works twice, then stops, in IE 9

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-9

I've got an MVC3 app. I'm calling the controller via ajax from a checkbox onclick method. After the click, I'm refreshing a Telerik grid. In Chrome and Firefox, this works fine. In IE9, it works for 2 clicks, then stops. What's up? Here's the code:

View code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="archived" onclick="javascript:ShowArchivedClicked();" id="archived" value="Archived" style="vertical-align:middle;" @{ if ((bool)Session[Const.ArchivedAttribute]) { <text>checked="checked"</text> } } /><span style="padding: 0 10px 0 0;"> Include archived records</span>


    function ShowArchivedClicked() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SetShowArchived", "Home")',
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function () {
                var summaryGrid = $("#SummaryGrid").data("tGrid");
                summaryGrid.rebind();
            },
            data: { showArchivedItems: $("#archived").is(":checked") }
        });
    }
```

Controller code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public void SetShowArchived(bool showArchivedItems)
        {
            ShowArchivedItems = showArchivedItems;
        }



        private bool ShowArchivedItems
        {
            get
            {
                return Session[Const.ArchivedAttribute] == null ? false : (bool)Session[Const.ArchivedAttribute];
            }
            set
            {
                Session[Const.ArchivedAttribute] = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you should have no need for using `onclick` inside the HTML code. You should be using jQuery's `click` method instead, like this: `$('#archived').click(function() {.....});`

Comment: What do you mean by two clicks?  Click once and it calls the action, then click another time and it doesn't?

Comment: One click checks the checkbox, calls the Action, and the grid refreshes. Click number two unchecks the checkbox, calls the Action, and the grid refreshes. Any more clicks don't appear to do anything. The Action is not called.

Comment: Attaching the event handler via jquery didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line to the ajax call did the trick:

```
cache: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `javascript:` from your `onclick`

all in `onclick` is javascript already... check out if this helps, if not, post a comment ;)

Comment: I originally didn't have the "javascript" there, but saw somewhere online that this might help in IE. Didn't seem to make a difference.